# How to get an RSS feed of tweets WITH images?

Tags: json, twitter, rss

I'm trying to get an rss feed of a list of tweets with a given hashtag, including the images that may be attached to the tweets.

I've used several different scripts out there, but none include the media_url entity that I believe I need, according to twitter's docs on API entities.  They do include other necessary things like author, tweet description, author profile pic, etc.

I've used [labnol's script](http://www.labnol.org/internet/twitter-rss-feeds/27931/), no luck.
I'm currently using [Twitter-RSS-Parser](https://github.com/jdelamater99/Twitter-RSS-Parser), which doesn't give me an image link either.

I'm not very familiar with any of the actual coding, just trying to piece together other people's findings.

Is there a way to edit either of these scripts to provide a link to the image attached to each tweet, or any other script out there that already does this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using tweedledee (can't find a link anymore!) scripts, which allow for specific queries and output in JSON.  From there I was able to format the JSON data as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Those labnol scripts will need the following parameter added to them `&include_entities=true`

That will ensure that Tweets which have photos will have their entity meta data returned.